# How to check whether a name is an alias or a reference in C++17?

Tags: c++, types, c++17, type-traits, structured-bindings

From [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding)

> Like a reference, a structured binding is an alias to an existing
>   object. Unlike a reference, the type of a structured binding does not
>   have to be a reference type.

For example:

```
int a[2] = { 1, 2 };
auto [x, y] = a;
```

`x` and `y` are aliases rather than references. My question:

**How to implement a type check function like `is_alias_v<decltype(x)>`?**

Comment: Why do you want such a function?

Comment: Note that in this specific example, `x` and `y` are aliases to elements of _a copy of_ `a`. (The copy has a "unique name", inaccessible from a valid program.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not believe that such a thing is possible.

Fortunately, there is never any need for it.

Use `x` as if it were a nice juicy `int`, regardless of its origins. Because, well, that's what it is!

Also don't forget that `x` and `y` here don't alias or reference the elements of `a`, but an "invisible" copy.

Comment: I even think most compilers simply create 2 `int`s instead of creating a copy and 2 aliases simply because there is no way to check

Comment: @Ayxan There's a way: `&x + 1 == &y` needs to be true.

Comment: @cpplearner why? C++ does not guarantee that members of a class are in a contagious memory block unlike arrays afaik.

Comment: @Ayxan Quite possible yeah!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Because `x` and `y` are aliases to array elements.

Comment: @cpplearner Okay, I suppose that's true -- but in practice `&x + 1 == &y` might also be true if they _weren't_ aliases to array elements, and in theory there's no well-defined way to actually observe/check that. So it's kind of a moot point

Answer (score 2):

An alias is either a type alias (e.g. `using Id = int`) or an alias template.

What is meant by a

> structured binding is an alias to an existing object

is that `[x, y]` as a whole is an alias (a new name) to an array of two ints (in this example). It has nothing to do with the name of the type of x alone.

If we have some type alias `using Id = int`, a type trait to know whether an `Id` is an `int` would be `std::is_same_t<Id, int>`. I don’t know how to implement a generic `is_alias_t<Id>`.

Comment: This is an interesting interpretation. But I don't think it's what cppreference wants to say.

Comment: What do you think cpp reference wants to say?

Comment: A type cannot alias another type. Two types are either the same or different. A *name* can be an alias (i.e. two different names can refer to the same thing). A structured binding is another name for an existing object. Alias is an ordinary English word and cppreference doesn't have to use it only in the way the standard is using it.

Comment: _"A type cannot alias another type."_ Except that's precisely what aliasing means

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No it doesn't, have you read my comment to the end?

Comment: Yes I read your whole comment. Fortunately your comment doesn't define the English language. If a type _aliases_ another type, that literally means they are actually the same type known by different names. It's literally what "to alias" means. That's the meaning of the word.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Alias, by definition, is an allernative *name* for the same *thing*. Look it up in the dictionary. This is exactly what I said in my comment. The crucial thing is that aliases are *different* but they name the *same thing*. It makes sense to say that a persom has several aliases (i.e. names), but not that a person aliases another person. This is nonsense. Same thing with types.

Comment: Guess we'll have to agree to disagree.